# How to pause a pausable token once issued

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

very good, I have created a pausable token, with the intention of then pausing it once it is issued if I need it. But I don't know how to do it after that, can someone help me?

Comment: What's the contract code? Are you using OpenZeppelin's Pausable contract? If you are using OZ then you should have added a function to call the internal function `_pause()`. Then just call that function.

Comment: yes the implemented Pausable Token Openzeppelin. What I mean is that once the token is compiled and released to the network. Being the owner of the contract, how can I pause it? how?

Comment: This is the contract you were using in another question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114395/my-token-erc20-does-not-issue-tokens/. You have to call `pause()` and `unpause()` function. It should be easier using a wallet that supports contracts, for example MyEtherWallet, MyCrypto and Remix+Metamask. Otherwise you could write a script that calls the function.

Comment: OK thank you very much. If I want to pause an already issued token, from remix + metamask how would it be?