# My Token erc20 does not issue tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 * @notice https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
 */
library SafeMath {
    /**
     * SafeMath mul function
     * @dev function for safe multiply, throws on overflow.
     **/
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * SafeMath div funciotn
     * @dev function for safe devide, throws on overflow.
     **/
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * SafeMath sub function
     * @dev function for safe subtraction, throws on overflow.
     **/
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }
    
    /**
     * SafeMath add function
     * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances.
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  uint256 totalSupply_;

  /**
  * @dev total number of tokens in existence
  */
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
  }

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Increase the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _addedValue The amount of tokens to increase the allowance by.
   */
  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = (
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue));
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Decrease the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To decrement
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _subtractedValue The amount of tokens to decrease the allowance by.
   */
  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  event OwnershipRenounced(address indexed previousOwner);
  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  /**
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to relinquish control of the contract.
   */
  function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
    emit OwnershipRenounced(owner);
    owner = address(0);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Pausable
 * @dev Base contract which allows children to implement an emergency stop mechanism.
 */
contract Pausable is Ownable {
  event Pause();
  event Unpause();
  event NotPausable();

  bool public paused = false;
  bool public canPause = true;

  /**
   * @dev Modifier to make a function callable only when the contract is not paused.
   */
  modifier whenNotPaused() {
    require(!paused || msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Modifier to make a function callable only when the contract is paused.
   */
  modifier whenPaused() {
    require(paused);
    _;
  }

  /**
     * @dev called by the owner to pause, triggers stopped state
     **/
    function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
        require(canPause == true);
        paused = true;
        emit Pause();
    }

  /**
   * @dev called by the owner to unpause, returns to normal state
   */
  function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
    require(paused == true);
    paused = false;
    emit Unpause();
  }
  
  /**
     * @dev Prevent the token from ever being paused again
     **/
    function notPausable() onlyOwner public{
        paused = false;
        canPause = false;
        emit NotPausable();
    }
}

/**
 * @title THEOSARS
 * @dev StandardToken modified with pausable transfers.
 **/
contract THEOSARS is StandardToken, Pausable {
    string public constant NAME = "THEOS ARS";
    string public constant SYMBOL = "ARST";
    uint256 public constant DECIMALS = 6;
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 500000000 * 10**18;
    /**
     * @dev Transfer tokens when not paused
     **/
    event Transfer (address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    
    /**
     * @dev transferFrom function to tansfer tokens when token is not paused
     **/
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev approve spender when not paused
     **/
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        return super.approve(_spender, _value);
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev increaseApproval of spender when not paused
     **/
    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
        return super.increaseApproval(_spender, _addedValue);
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev decreaseApproval of spender when not paused
     **/
    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
        return super.decreaseApproval(_spender, _subtractedValue);
    }
    
    /**
   * TheosARS Token Constructor
   * @dev Create and issue tokens to msg.sender.
   */
  constructor() public {
    totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please do some homework before asking! What do you exactly mean with 'does not issue tokens'? Which function are you calling? What's the expected result? What's the result obtained? Did you deploy to a testnet? Do you have a failed transaction hash?

Comment: Yes excuse me, what I mean is that I have tested my code in remix and it passes fine. When I try to test the token on matik's testnet. It just doesn't issue tokens.

Comment: The expected result is that it issues 100,000 token (I know that in the code it appears as initialSup 500000000 * 10 ** 18) and that the price of the security remains in relation to FIAT, that is, a stablecoin. And I integrated pausable token from oppenzeplin.

Answer (score 0):

The contract `THEOSARS` has several issues:

1. The mappings `balances` and `allowed` are duplicated in `THEOSARS`, `StandardToken` and `BasicToken`

   ```
   mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
   mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
   ```

   Solidity creates two unrelated copies. More recent version of solc issue a warning when two variables with the same name are used in inherited contracts.
2. The variables names don't follow [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20)

   ```
   string public constant NAME = "THEOS ARS";
   string public constant SYMBOL = "ARST";
   uint256 public constant DECIMALS = 6;
   ```

   They should be in lowercase.
3. No `Transfer` event is emitted when minting tokens in the constructor.

Comment: thanks for the help, but still no token issuance. Here the test of the contract with a balance 0 https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x908cC927e491eB378cED58FA148eFd22a974C27D

Comment: @HM.schrodinger What's the contract code? What exactly do you mean with "token issuance"? Another missing thing is there's no Transfer event when minting tokens. Also you should consider that sometimes Etherscan/Polygonscan do not update testing networks immediately when a token is created.